# Generate huffman tree on Nvidia GPU

Tags: cuda, nvidia, huffman-code

Is there a way to recreate a huffman tree on the GPU using only the frequency and symbol? Also is it fast or even worth the trouble to do?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Huffman code is not uniquely determined by the frequencies of the symbols.  There are many different optimal codes for the same set of frequencies.

What you want is a [canonical Huffman code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code), which defines exactly what code to generate given only the symbols and the number of bits for each symbol.  You do not need to transmit frequencies or a tree.